# Possible to add a command to be run when a currently running command completes?

Tags: command-line

When running time consuming processes in terminal, I like to add something like `say "done"` as an additional command so that I can get alerted when the current process ends. For example:

```
$ do_this_long_thing; say "done";
```

Works great. But sometimes I forget the `say "done"` command, only to realize it once the long command is already running. Is there a way to add that additional command to the queue once a command is already running?

Comment: Create a script that holds these commands. Execute that script :-)

Comment: Yes, I generally do that. But sometimes there are one-off commands for which that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: So the script becomes a bit more difficult: Alter the last part to execute only when time_end -/- time_started > x seconds. By the way: I would not bother. If a scripts runs long I tend to "nohup" + "&" it and let it run.

Comment: In the terminal running the long running command, just type `say done` and hit enter. When the long running command finishes, shell will take what you typed as the next command to run. This assumes the long running command is not going to need to read anything from stdin.

Comment: @glennjackman well that was easy! Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terminal running the long running command, just type say done and hit enter. When the long running command finishes, shell will take what you typed as the next command to run. This assumes the long running command is not going to need to read anything from stdin,

Answer (score 7):

> My solutions is this: suspend your long-running task with Control+Z,
>   then type something like:
>
> ```
> fg; echo "Done!"
> ```
>
> If you want to run react differently based on the success or failure
>   of your command, use && and || as short-circuit operators.
>
> ```
> fg && echo "Success!" || echo "Failure!"
> ```

Source: [How to execute command after current running command in bash?](//superuser.com/q/35179)

Comment: David, there is a problem with `fg && echo "Success!" || echo "Failure!"` ..teh command after `||` will run if any one of the previous commands (before and after `&&`) fails..although its unlikely that `echo` will fail but possible..

Comment: I agree, but consider this argument purely academical. What are the odds, that the first `echo` fails (most likely because of an invalid standard output file descriptor), but the second `echo` succeeds and prints its message? I also didn't really want to change the citation without a good reason.

Comment: Thank you David!  This makes perfect sense now to me.  If I run a command like: `sudo apt -f && echo "Success" || echo "Failed"`, it will produce Failed because the first echo line did not run as the command itself failed.   Great explanation.  =)